# Accessing website(Laravel in Digitalocean Droplet) through the droplet IP is working, but using the registered domain is showing 404

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, server, digital-ocean

I have deployed a Laravel Project on a Digitalocean droplet, and serving it using NGINX. 
Everything is working fine while trying to access the webpage through the IP `https://<Droplet_IP>/` (https is enabled, but when it wasn't enabled, the same problem was present.)

But, when I try to access the same webpage through the registered domain `https://<domain_name>/` I'm getting `404 error page` - this is the **custom error page** made by us. Very weird. 
Trying to access **ANY** link using the domain results in the **404 error page**, meanwhile the same action while accessing through the **Droplet IP** works like a charm.

Ofcourse, I've set the DNS records in Digitalocean, both the `@` and `www` records. 
Also, have updated the `NS` on the **domain registrar** with Digitalocean **Nameservers**.

I've also gone through different configuration of NGINX, trying various solutions out from the internet, and my latest NGINX config is below:

```
    server_name domain www.domain;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$is_args$args;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    #error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/habitoz.in/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/habitoz.in/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.habitoz.in) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = habitoz.in) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name domain www.domain;
    #return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Right now, I'm at a loss as to what to do. 
How is the website working perfectly through the IP, but not through the domain. 
And, if there was a problem with the domain in the first place, how is the custom 404 page being shown. 
That means that the application is working, but somehow, something is amiss when accessing through the domain.

Comment: did you configured in `/etc/nginx/sites-available`?

Comment: Yes. It's configured correctly. Otherwise, the site wouldn't be served through the IP in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Spend the whole day & night, and couldn't figure out the answer. When I woke up in the morning, the answer clicked in me.

A very simple, and idiotic error it turned out to be!

When I deployed the app in the droplet, I modified the `.env` file, and changed `APP_URL` to the `<Droplet_IP>` but when I linked the droplet to the domain, I skipped the step to change the **APP_URL**, and it's such a small thing, that I don't remember that I skipped that step.

All my error checks, and trying out different solutions amounted to nothing, yet it didn't strike me to check the `.env` file. 
Once the `APP_URL` is modified to point to the right URL, the error was gone.